# form th:action is giving exception Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringActionTagProcessor'

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

When I render a page to a specific URL, it is throwing an error because of the action attribute in the form. I don't know why it is happening. Advance Thanks for looking at this. Other code details are given below.

Controller :

```
@GetMapping("/users/new")
    public String newUser(Model model){
        List<Role> listRoles = userService.listRoles();

        User user  = new User();
        user.setEnabled(true);

        model.addAttribute("user",user);
        model.addAttribute("listRoles",listRoles);

        return "add_user";
    }

    @PostMapping("/users/save")
    public String saveUser(User user, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
        System.out.println(user);
        userService.save(user);

        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message","The user has saved Successfully.");

        return "redirect:/users";
    }
```

It is getting error when I call the 'user/new' url. When I removed that th:action attribute it is working and not showing any other errors. I don't what is happening. When I have removed method attribute the error gone.

add_form.html:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/user/save}" method="post"  th:object="${user}">
                    <div class="row mb-3">
                      <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"
                             for="basic-icon-default-email">Email</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <div class="input-group input-group-merge">
                          <span class="input-group-text"><i class="bx bx-envelope"></i></span>
                          <input type="email"
                                 id="basic-icon-default-email"
                                 class="form-control"
                                 placeholder="Your Email"
                                 aria-label="Email"
                                 th:field="*{email}"
                                 required
                                 minlength="8"
                                 maxlength="128"
                                 aria-describedby="basic-icon-default-email2"
                          />
                          <span id="basic-icon-default-email2" class="input-group-text">@example.com</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-text">You can use letters, numbers & periods</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row mb-3">
                      <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="basic-icon-default-fullname2">Full
                        Name</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">

                        <div class="input-group">
                              <span id="basic-icon-default-fullname2" class="input-group-text"
                              ><i class="bx bx-user"></i
                              ></span>
                          <input type="text"
                                 aria-label="First name"
                                 placeholder="First Name"
                                 th:field="*{firstName}"
                                 required
                                 minlength="3"
                                 maxlength="45"
                                 class="form-control"/>
                          <input type="text"
                                 aria-label="Last name"
                                 placeholder="Last Name"
                                 th:field="*{lastName}"
                                 required
                                 minlength="3"
                                 class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>



                    <div class="row mb-3 form-password-toggle">
                      <label class="col-sm-2 form-label"
                             for="basic-default-password32">Password</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <div class="input-group input-group-merge">
                                <span id="basic-icon-default-password" class="input-group-text"
                                ><i class="bx bx-lock"></i
                                ></span>
                          <input
                                  type="password"
                                  th:field="*{password}"
                                  required
                                  minlength="8"
                                  maxlength="20"
                                  class="form-control"
                                  id="basic-default-password32"
                                  placeholder="&#xb7;&#xb7;&#xb7;&#xb7;&#xb7;&#xb7;&#xb7;&#xb7;&#xb7;&#xb7;&#xb7;&#xb7;"
                                  aria-describedby="basic-default-password"
                          />
                          <span class="input-group-text cursor-pointer"
                                id="basic-default-password"
                          ><i class="bx bx-hide"></i
                          ></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mb-3">
                      <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="defaultCheck1">Roles</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <div class="col-md">
                          <small class="text-light fw-semibold">Available roles</small>
                          <th:block th:each="role : ${listRoles}">
                            <div class="form-check mt-3">
                              <input th:field="*{roles}"
                                     th:value="${role.id}"
                                     class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1" />
                              <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1" th:text="${role.name}">roleName</label>
                              - <small> [[${role.description}]]</small>
                            </div>
                          </th:block>


                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="row mb-3">
                      <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="defaultCheck1">Enabled?</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <div class="col-md">
                          <small class="text-light fw-semibold">Is this user want to be enabled?</small>
                          <div class="form-check mt-3">
                            <input th:field="*{enabled}"
                                   class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1" />
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">Enable</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row mb-3">
                      <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="basic-icon-default-photos">Photos</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <div class="input-group input-group-merge">
                          <span class="input-group-text"><i class="bx bx-user"></i></span>
                          <input class="form-control" id="basic-icon-default-photos" type="file"/>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="row justify-content-end">
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add User</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
```

Terminal Error:

```
2022-10-22 22:13:54.636 ERROR 67100 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Exception processing template "add_user": Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringActionTagProcessor' (template: "add_user" - line 585, col 36)

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringActionTagProcessor' (template: "add_user" - line 585, col 36)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:117) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigu
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringActionTagProcessor.doProcess(SpringActionTagProcessor.java:118) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.java:160) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateModel.process(TemplateModel.java:136) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:661) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:366) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1405) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1149) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1088) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilter(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:67) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:337) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]


2022-10-22 22:13:54.749 ERROR 67100 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.e.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$StaticView : Cannot render error page for request [/admin/users/new] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code.
```

Comment: It is not showing when method attribute is removed. When both them are there it is still showing error.

Answer (score 0):

Your endpoint is `/users/save` instead of `/user/save`.

Use `th:action="@{/users/save}"` and it should be working fine. No need to add `action="#"` either.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But problem with th:action is not gone. I identified the problem. It is because of csrf token. I disabled in spring security configuration. Now it is working. But my form's not getting the default csrf token. Do you know why is that?

Comment: That is a different issue from the `th:action` though. Ensure you have the dependency `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4` in your project, this alongside with `th:action` will help with adding the csrf token automatically in the form.

Comment: yess! But my this form does not have csrf token automatically. I think it is beacause of the template. When I changed the form completely it is getting csrf automatically. Anyway Thanks bro !!!